# Laravel - Creating bootstrap dropdown for each parent in a nested set

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade, nested-sets

I am using [etrepat/baum](https://github.com/etrepat/baum) to create the categories for my application in a laravel project. I have a problem when using `@foreach` in blade when I want to create bootstrap dropdown menus for the categories. This works just fine when the structure is like so:

```
<nav id="nav2" role="navigation">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Shop by Category<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        @foreach($catnav as $cat) @if($cat->depth == 0)
        <li>
          {{ HTML::link(URL::action('StoreController@getCategories', [$cat->slug]), $cat->name) }} @else($cat->depth == 1)
          <ul>
            <li><a href="{{ URL::to('/store/categories/' . implode('/', $cat->getAncestorsAndSelf()->lists('slug'))) }}">{{$cat->name}}</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        @endif @endforeach
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

This is the output to the above:

[image]

But I don't want to have a *Shop by Category* dropdown, but I am trying to make a `dropdown` for each of the parent categories to contain the children in the `dropdown-menu`. I tried this structure, but the `@foreach` will mess with the layout.

```
<nav id="nav2" role="navigation">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    @foreach($catnav as $cat) @if($cat->depth == 0)
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ HTML::link(URL::action('StoreController@getCategories', [$cat->slug]), $cat->name, array('class'=>'dropdown-toggle' ,'data-toggle'=>'dropdown')) }}<span class="caret"></span></a>
      @else($cat->depth == 1)
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="{{ URL::to('/store/categories/' . implode('/', $cat->getAncestorsAndSelf()->lists('slug'))) }}">{{$cat->name}}</a>
        </li>
        @endif
      </ul>
    </li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
</nav>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a long day trying to figure this out I ended up:

- Using the `toHierarchy()` method to return a nested collection of the queried tree.
- Using a `@foreach` loop to get all the parent nodes and inside another `@foreach` to get the children.
- Using the `isRoot()` function to check if the item is a parent.
- Using `isLeaf()` function to check if is the end of a branch.
- Using lots of `@if` statements.

**Solution**:

```
<nav id="nav2" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    @foreach($catnav as $item)
        <li @if($item->isRoot())class ="dropdown"@endif>
            @if(!$item->isLeaf())
                <a @if($item->isRoot()) class="dropdown-toggle"@endif href="/store/categories/{{ $item->slug }}">
                {{ $item->name }}
                @if($item->isRoot()) <span class="caret"></span> @endif
                </a>
            @else
                <a href="/store/categories/{{ $item->slug }}">{{$item->name}}</a>
            @endif
            @if($item->isRoot() && !$item->isLeaf())
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                @foreach($item->children as $child)
                  <li><a href="{{ URL::to('/store/categories/'.implode('/', $child->getAncestorsAndSelf()->lists('slug'))) }}">{{$child->name}}</a></li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
            @endif
        </li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [package I created to easily create Dropdown Menu](https://github.com/secrethash/dropmenu) and to just focus on development.

You can create the drop down menu just by using this code:

- Blade:

  ```
  {!! Dropmenu::display('MenuName') !!}
  ```
- Controller:

  ```
  $menu = Dropmenu::display('MenuName');
  return view('name.view', ['menu' => $menu]);
  ```